# Create Android app & signed with cmd command in windows

Tags: android, ant, command

i am need to a way that can make app from source code & signed it  to finally create apk signed file .

i have source code but i havent  not going use eclipse for compile app .

have a wat to compile with command from C# code or other language ??

sorry for bad english .

Comment: Plz add link to see better answer . thnks

Answer (score 0):

Either the current standard build system for Android (Gradle) or the previous one (Maven) will provide a command-line interface through which you can build and package your app.